# How to efficiently replace special characters in an XML in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype, xmltable

I'm parsing an xml in oracle sql.

```
XMLType(replace(column1,'&','<![CDATA[&]]>')) //column1 is a column name that has xml data
```

While parsing, I'm temporarily wrapping '&' in CDATA to prevent any xml exception. After getting rid of the exception caused by '&', I'm getting "invalid character 32 (' ') found in a Name or Nmtoken". This is because of '<' character.

```
E.g: <child> 40 < 50 </child> // This causes the above exception.
```

So I tried the below and it works.

```
XMLType(replace(replace(column1,'&','<![CDATA[&]]>'),'< ','<![CDATA[< ]]>'))
```

In the above, I'm wrapping '< '(less than symbol followed by space) in CDATA. But the above is a bit time consuming. So I'm trying to use regex to reduce the time taken.
Does anyone know how to implement the above action using regex in Oracle sql??

```
 Input : <child> 40 & < 50 </child>
 Expected Output : <child> 40 <![CDATA[&]]> <![CDATA[< ]]> 50 </child>
```

Note: Replacing '& ' with ampersand semicolon sometimes is leading to 'entity reference not well formed' exception. Hence I have opted to wrap in CDATA.

Comment: please edit the question, and post a valid xml and expected output for a [mcve]. thanks

Comment: Why do you use `REPLACE`? Use build-in function [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a regexp like this:

```
select regexp_replace(sr.column1,'(&|< )','<![CDATA[\1]]>') from dual;
```

However, `regexp_replace` (and all the `regexp_*` functions) are often slower than using plain `replace`, because they do more complicated logic. So I'm not sure if it'll be faster or not.

You might already be aware, but your underlying problem here is that you're starting out with **invalid XML** that you're trying to fix, which is a hard problem! The ideal solution is to not have invalid XML in the first place - if possible, you should escape special characters *when originally generating your XML*. There are built-in functions which can do that quickly, like [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100) or [HTF.ESCAPE_SC](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_htf.htm#ARPLS70276).

Comment: It's not just a hard problem, it's technically impossible. There is no 100% reliable algorithm that will correctly distinguish "<" characters at the start of a tag from "<" characters that were accidentally left unescaped in content, and an algorithm that gets anywhere close will require ridiculous amounts of look-ahead.